# Querying DB from inside Spring Condition

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, conditional-statements

I have two services, that both implement the same Interface.
I am trying to use Springs @Conditional annotation to decide which one to initialize depending on the configuration. Due to the Fact that i have to deal with legacy software the configuration is stored inside the DB and has to stay there. So i have to make a query inside my condition. I would like to use SpringData for that but when i Autowire the Repository into my `org.springframework.context.annotation.Condition` it is null. I even tried to get the Repo using the `ConditionContext` like `context.getBeanFactory().getBean(SystemSettingRepository.class)` but that produces an exception.
Can you think of any way to query the DB from inside a Condition?
Here is my Code:

```
public class UseCMISCondition implements Condition {
    @Autowired
    private SystemSettingRepository settingsRepo;

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return settingsRepo.useCMIS();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your Help.

Comment: Don't. Instead load the configuration as part of the rest of the configuration (in a `PropertySource`) and use a regular `@ConditionalOnProperty` expression.

Comment: in order autowire your repository `UseCMISCondition` needs to be a `@Component`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your beter off with a Configuration that provides a ServiceBean depending on the result of your query?

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceProvider {
  @Autowired  private SystemSettingRepository settingsRepo;

  @Bean
  public MyInterface myIneterface(){
      boolean cmis = settingsRepo.useCMIS() ;
      if(cmis){
        return xMyService();
      } else {
        return yMyService();
      }
  }

  private XMyService xMyService(){
      return new XMyService();
  }

  private YMyService yMyService(){
      return new YMyService();
  }

}
```

Comment: I discovered that i did something wrong. I need one of the two beens depending on the user that is using it. Your solution would have worked under the circumstances that i described above, so you will get the upvote.